# Erro ao executar comando make com plugin de repositorio

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, repository

Quando executo o comando `php artisan make:entity User` ele retorna o erro

```
[ReflectionException]
Method Prettus\Repository\Generators\Commands\EntityCommand::handle() does not exist
```

Fiz a instalação como diz na documentação, com essa sequencia de comandos(windows).

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
laravel new project
composer require prettus/l5-repository
Coloquei `Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,` em `config/app`
php artisan make:entity User
```

Comment: Qual é o pacote?

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/prettus/l5-repository

Comment: Acabei de fazer a instalação e funcionou normalmente

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando uma lista de comandos que usei.

Comment: Na sua pergunta tá prettus/l5-require e no comentário l5-repository?

Comment: Atualizei, acabei me confundindo.

Comment: foi isso mesmo que eu fiz no config/app.php se colocou `Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class` aonde?

Comment: Coloquei isso dentro dos Providers

Comment: se faltou fazer isso eu acho: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider "Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider"`

Comment: Sim, eu fiz no meu PC a uns dias e funcionou, e agora simplesmente parou de funcionar, eu já fiz esse comando também, e não tenho a minima ideia do que possa ser.

Comment: é talvez seja algum pacote adicionado a esses dias, que pode está te atrapalhando, um pente fino... verifique o que você fez nos últimos dias ...

Comment: Na verdade eu formatei hoje, está com o Windows 10 zerado, vou ver oque pode ser, obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: já tentou `php composer.phar dumpautoload`

Comment: Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: tem que baixar colocar na pasta da aplicação novamente e rodar o comando acho que é falta de load dos pacotes

Comment: Eu já usei `composer dumpautoload`, ele carrega tudo, mas o erro continua

Comment: Bom é alguma coisa particular não temos como reproduzir

Comment: Sim, entendo, obrigado de qualquer forma